# How can LPWA get implemented

Tags: anonymity

I have been reading about computer security and at a point it mentioned Lucent Personalized Web Assistant (LPWA). Though I think I understood what it can offer, it doesn't say anywhere how/if a user can implement it. Also the website www.lpwa.com which it mentioned doesn't lead anywhere. Any ideas?

P.S I haven't been able to find it either on tags that is why I did not mention it.

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange! Could you tell us where LPWA was mentioned?

Comment: @S.L.Barth I have a book from my University which is written in my native language and i don't think it has been translated at least yet. An article about it which has relevant info can be found here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.145.7899&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: A Google search is coming up with rich results.